# Autorefresh opened figure when updated in Linux OS (e.g. displayed on Image Magick)

Tags: linux, image, imagemagick, x11

When plotting figures (e.g. python), without showing them within the program (i.e. not using show()), is it possible to keep the figure displayed (X11) and automatically updated when modified in Linux? Having this function saves a lot of time from reopening the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display -update 1 file.jpg` on ImageMagick's display, and it will check for updates once per second.

qiv (another Linux image visualizer) checks the file for updates without the 1 second delay, when run with `qiv -T file.jpg`